# a javascript function only works once on page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use this example to create modal pop ups for image:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

I have most everything working as needed however I can not seem to make it work more than once on the same page.

I am generating file lists in php and that is sure to complicate it too.

There is a try it editor of this code here
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img

ultimately I need this to wrap around my links generated in PHP.

```js
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

    #myImg {
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

     /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
      display: none; /* Hidden by default */
      position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
      padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%; /* Full width */
      height: 100%; /* Full height */
      overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content (image) */
    .modal-content {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
    }

    /* Caption of Modal Image */
    #caption {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ccc;
      padding: 10px 0;
      height: 150px;
    }

    /* Add Animation */
    .modal-content, #caption {  
      -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
      animation-name: zoom;
      animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
      from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
      to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
    }

    @keyframes zoom {
      from {transform:scale(0)} 
      to {transform:scale(1)}
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #bbb;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
      .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
   <img id="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%; max-width:300px">

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Looks like you are off to a good start. How about adding a second image with a different id. The set a click handler on that one that shows it in your modal dialog? That will demonstrate how to do more than one. Next, you'll realize you want to deal with your modal in a separate function and separate out the function from the event handler. That will get you on your way.

Comment: Seems to work, what was the question?

Comment: adding the second image is precisely where it stops working. I am not so familiar with javascript. Also I would have to use filenames from php as names . You say "id" however there are "myImg", "img01" and "caption" all appear to be IDs .

Comment: Matthew Page, I need multiple modals from the same page. I do not know how to get that working

Comment: posting here seems very limited. I used your code here is a snip of browser uotput generated from php that is not working with images.
<a href='Scan20190125231015.jpg'><span style='color:#777AFF; font-weight:bold'>Scan20190125231015.jpg</a></span></td><td><a href='deletefile.php?delfile=Scan20190125231015.jpg'><span style='color:#770000; font-weight:bold'>Delete File</span></a></td><td><img
      id='img13'
      src='Scan20190125231015.jpg'
      alt='Scan20190125231015.jpg'
      style='width:auto;max-width:100px;height:auto;max-height:100px'
      class='js-img'

Comment: I got it working 
I had
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img1");
must be
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

thanks

Comment: No idea what the DOM is but i formatted some rather Submissive php code to give me what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If we want to be able to click on multiple images we can add a class to all your images (in the example below : `js-img`).
Thanks to that class you can query back those elements and loop over each to add a `onclick` listener.

We can see here a working example : https://jsfiddle.net/k8woxf0s/3/

Main code is (loop) :

```
Array.from(imgs).forEach(function(img) {
  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  };
})
```

`Array.from` is necessary because `getElementsByClassName` do not return an array but a HTMLCollection : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName .

You can use `querySelectorAll` (which is a more recent function), see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Now you have to write the code to generate the DOM for your images (PHP code).

Hope that it helps you :).

Comment: Tchize, thanks foo such a complete answer. I am however a little confused on a couple of points after installing your suggestions/ My PHP produces the following

Comment: Tchize, thanks so such a complete answer. I am however a little confused on a couple of points after installing your suggestions. I am unable to post code in comments here and not sure how to deal with that. My class='js-image and id='img1' through id='img50'. When an image is clicked it is not opening image only caption and I noticed in your jsfiddle one id was completely different.

Comment: Without any code it is hard to guess the problem :/. You may edit your question to add an update with some code. You may paste the code generated by your PHP (view source in your browser).
If only the caption is display it may be because the `modalImg` variable is not correct. Is the id correct and unique in the page for the img in the modal ?